# Dynamically select dropdown menu values based on HTML checkbox

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I have a form with an HTML checkbox and two dropdown/select menus. If I check the checkbox, it should dynamically select values in the dropdown menus.

**Unfortunately, I am having trouble getting this to work as it seems I have to manually select the values to make them appear.**

If you check the box for *"Top Rated"*, it should dynamically select `Watermelon` product and `Black Diamond` as the product subject.

Sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/restrict-values-on-toggle-mxiq3

Any tips and advice would be greatly appreciated

> PostForm.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="form.topRated"> Top Rated
      <br>
      <br>
      <label for="product_select_input">Product:</label>
      <select v-if="form.topRated" id="product_select_input" v-model="form.product_id">
        <option value="3">Watermelon</option>
      </select>
      <select v-if="form.topRated==false" id="product_select_input" v-model="form.product_id">
        <option disabled value>Select</option>
        <option
          v-for="(product, index) in products"
          :key="index"
          :value="product.product_id"
        >{{ product.product_name }}</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <label for="product_subject_input">Product Subject:</label>
      <select v-if="form.topRated" id="product_subject_input" v-model="form.subject_id">
        <option value="5">Black Diamond</option>
      </select>
      <select v-if="form.topRated==false" id="product_subject_input" v-model="form.subject_id">
        <option disabled value>Select a Subject</option>
        <option
          v-for="(subject, index) in showRelatedSubj"
          :key="index"
          :value="subject"
        >{{ subject.subject_name }}</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
    </form>

    <pre>
      <div>form: {{form}}</div>
      <!-- <div>related subjects: {{showRelatedSubj}}</div> -->
    </pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "PostForm",
  data() {
    return {
      products: [
        {
          product_id: 1,
          product_name: "Apple"
        },
        {
          product_id: 2,
          product_name: "Banana"
        },
        {
          product_id: 3,
          product_name: "Watermelon"
        },
        {
          product_id: 4,
          product_name: "Potato"
        }
      ],
      subjects: [
        {
          subject_id: 1,
          product_id: 1,
          subject_name: "Granny Smith"
        },
        {
          subject_id: 2,
          product_id: 1,
          subject_name: "McIntosh"
        },
        {
          subject_id: 3,
          product_id: 2,
          subject_name: "Cavendish"
        },
        {
          subject_id: 4,
          product_id: 3,
          subject_name: "Jubilee"
        },
        {
          subject_id: 5,
          product_id: 3,
          subject_name: "Black Diamond"
        },
        {
          subject_id: 6,
          product_id: 4,
          subject_name: "Russet"
        },
        {
          subject_id: 7,
          product_id: 4,
          subject_name: "Yukon Gold"
        }
      ],
      form: {
        topRated: false,
        product_id: "",
        subject_id: ""
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    showRelatedSubj() {
      return this.subjects.filter(
        subject => this.form.product_id === subject.product_id
      );
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add a change event listener to your `input checkbox` and set a method for that event.

```
  <input @change="select_top_rated()" type="checkbox" v-model="form.topRated"> 


select_top_rated() {
      if (this.form.topRated){
      this.form.product_id = 3
      this.form.subject_id = 5
      } else{
        this.form.product_id = null
        this.form.subject_id = null
      }
    }
```

for disabling the select options after checking `Top Rated` checkbox, try attribute binding. `:disabled` in this case.

```
<select :disabled="select_disabled" v-if="form.topRated" id="product_select_input" v-model="form.product_id">
        <option value="3">Watermelon</option>
      </select>
```

define `select_disabled` in your data, set it to false initially. 
and add this to your `select_top_rated()` method.

```
this.select_disabled = true
```

Comment: That was helpful, thanks! Quick question, do you know how I could disable the selects so user can't choose another product and subject value?